# Android application getting restarted while in foreground

Tags: android

I've been having an issue with an android application. The application is getting restart while in foreground. I know that background activity can get killed and will be recreate when returning to them but in this scenario the foreground activity is getting killed.
There is no exception happening, doesn't seems to be memory related since it's stable for the app.
This also happen at different point in the app, not always in the same spot.

I do have a application class that start when the app start and we can see in the log that class starting when this happen.
For example
activity1 call activity2
activity2 getting killed and then activity1 getting created
When this happen we can see the screen turn white.
Sometime it will restart even if only activity1 is open
It is a bit like using the "don't keep activity alive" in dev option but the foreground activity didn't finish to process.

Is this a knowed behavior in android? I always thought only background activity can get killed by the os.

Thank you,

Comment: have you looked at the output of logcat? (or device log)

Comment: That's a good point, let me check that

Comment: I can see this Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 4435 (FinalizerDaemon)